# Does shell map restrict the key format?

Tags: linux, shell, dictionary

```
 a=()
 a["/dev"]=3
 echo ${a["/dev"]}
```

Run the above code will get error:

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/dev")
```

If I modify key='dev', it works. So, the key only can be a simple string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare the array associative first:

```
declare -A a
a["/dev"]=3
echo ${a["/dev"]}
```